# How to import or use only child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

For example I have these components

`first.js`

```
<div>
   <Route path='/' />
   <Route path='/first' />
</div>
```

`second.js`

```
<div>
    <Route path='/second' />
    <Redirect to='/something' />
</div>
```

And then i have a component that has this

```
<Switch>
    <First>
    <Second>
</Switch>
```

I am using React-Router and `Switch` does not work if it's child components are not `Route`. So how does one just strip those divs from first and second components so only things left are the routes?

Comment: Why don't you keep routes in one file ? In the Switch tag ?

Comment: This is just an example, I have few components with switches and lots of routes in them and want to implement a not found component if user would use an unknown path. But the only way to make a 'default' route is to have all routes in one switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return them in an array:

```
return [
  <Route path='/' key='root' />,
  <Route path='/first' key='first' />
]
```

**Note:** returning an array is necessary to provide a key props.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap them in fragment like this:

```
<React.Fragment>
  <Route path='/' />
  <Route path='/first' />
</React.Fragment>
```